# how connect to mysql with socket or curl

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, curl

i will connect to mysql witout mysql_connect
but have an error :)

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com:3306');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$fields = "user=root&pass=";
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
if (empty($buffer)){
    print "Nothing returned from url.<p>";
}
else{
    print $buffer;
}
```

has error like

5.5.27)500>)P7cÿ÷€n|I3cxQnVC,Omysql_native_password!ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocol to communicate with MySQL is not HTTP, so you cannot use an HTTP client like cURL.

If you want to use sockets directly, then start with the [PHP sockets library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) (the first thing you should do is to [open a connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php).

Then you'll need to implement [the MySQL protocol, which is described in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html).

That said, while [you shouldn't use `mysql_`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068), there are [good replacement libraries that exist](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) already.

Comment: tnx so how connect with socket to mysql?

Comment: `socket_connect($socket, $address, $port)`